# WPF ComboBox in DataGrid Doesn't Display Selected Value

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, combobox

I have a `datagrid` with a template column and a `combobox` inside it. I also have another `combobox` which is not inside the `datagrid`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource asientoDetallesAsientosViewSource}}" 
        Name="detallesAsientosDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Cuenta">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                            Name="combo1"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cuentaListaViewSource}}"
                            SelectedValuePath="Numero"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Nombre"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=detallesAsientosDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.Numero}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Numero}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<ComboBox Name="combo2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cuentaListaViewSource}}"  
            SelectedValuePath="Numero"
            DisplayMemberPath="Nombre"
            SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=detallesAsientosDataGrid,
                            Path=SelectedItem.Numero}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Now the strange thing and the problem is that in this case the `combo1` inside the `datagrid`, when in edit mode, shows correctly the selected row value BUT if I delete the `combo2` the `combo1` stops working and doesn't anymore show the selected row value but instead the first value of the `combobox` list.

Why does it happen? The `combo2` is exactly the same `combobox` as the `combo1`.

Answer (score 1):

They both bind to the same SelectedValue.  If you delete (edit) the SelectedValue then the selected value is no longer in the ItemsSource.   If you select (not edit) a value from the pull down does it work?